# Try/catch not catching HttpListenerException

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener, grapevine

I made a simple http endpoint using Grapevine (which is just an interface for HttpListener). Sometimes the connection drops before I `SendResponse` which leads to a HttpListenerException, but I don't understand why the try/catch doesn't handle the exception and the whole server crashes.

Error:

```
Application: Movimiento de Placas.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.HttpListenerException
Stack:
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.HttpResponse.SendResponse(Byte[])
   at Grapevine.Server.HttpResponseExtensions.SendResponse(Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.IHttpResponse, System.String)
   at Grapevine.Server.Router.Route(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Code:

```
[RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.POST, PathInfo = "/patente")]
        public IHttpContext ModificarPantalla(IHttpContext context)
        {
            var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.Payload);
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                dict.Keys.Cast<string>()
                    .ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]));
            var contenido = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patente>(json);
            Server.FormRef.CargarPatente(contenido.Plate, contenido.idCamera);
            UltimaFoto.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            Task.Run(() => Sqlite.InsertarPatente(contenido));
            try
            {
                context.Response.SendResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok); //exception occurs here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return context;
        }
```

Comment: Your catch doesn't DO anything. What are you going to do even if you do catch an exception?

Comment: Avoid the whole program crashing, that's the point. I don't need to do anything when the connection drops.

Comment: @Vallo I just published 4.1.2, should be available shortly on nuget.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. There is a PR that's been hanging around for a while now that fixes this, I'm merging it in now, along with an update that will add support for .NET Standard. This should be available by the end of the week.

> Update: Grapevine 4.1.2 is available on Nuget.org as of August 9, 2019

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if SendResponse was async and you didnt await it.

Comment: SendResponse is not async.
`namespace Grapevine.Server
{
    public static class HttpResponseExtensions
    {
        public static void SendResponse(this IHttpResponse response, HttpStatusCode statusCode);
}
}`

Comment: I wonder if it's the case deeper in that method somewhere then. Some Task.Run call maybe just like you have in your example.  I can't see how it would escape that block otherwise. Maybe the exception is throwing from elsewhere and you think its from that try?

Comment: pretty sure that's the line causing it, since that's the only endpoint in my program. I should start looking at Grapevine source code to understand why the exception is not being catched.